# Error when printing specific information from array - "Warning: Illegal string offset 'id'"

Tags: php, arrays, json

When i try to print specific items in the array "entry_history" , i get an error. For example when i am printing ID it gives me the following error:

> "Warning: Illegal string offset 'id'"

```
<?PHP
foreach($data['entry_history'] as $key=>$item)
{ 

?>
<td><?PHP echo $item['id']; ?></td>
<?PHP
}
?>
```

Comment: `$item` is a string, not an array.

Comment: @Barmar Good point :)

Comment: `$data['entry_history']` is a 1-dimensional array, not a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: To ask for help it is a good idea to show the code and the data as well. Can you show us a `var_dump($data)`

Comment: Thank you guys or your response. I actually am editing a code from github. Here is the link to the code https://github.com/pkgrem/OddsOnFPL/blob/master/fplinfo.php  . The error is on line 81.

Comment: @Barmar, if its a 1 dimensional array, how can i print specific values from the array ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly here you go, this is the data i am retrieving from the api https://fantasy.premierleague.com/drf/entry/1/event/1/picks

Comment: You want `$data['entry_history']['id']`.

Comment: Or `$data->entry_history->id` if you didnt convert it all to an array in the `json_decode()`

Comment: @Zain Why wouldn't you be able to print specific values from a 1-dimensional array? But you can't treat the values as nested arrays, since they're scalar.

Comment: @Barmar and RiggsFolly thank you so much! Can you please explain what i was doing wrong? Isn't 'entry_history' an array?

Comment: Yes, it's an array, but it's not a 2-dimensional array. `id` is a key in `entry_history`, but you looped through each element of the array, and tried to access the `id` key of the element.

Comment: Your code would work for `"event_history": [ { "id" => ... }, {"id" => ...}, ...]` See the difference?

Comment: Look at `picks` for an example of an array of objects.

Comment: @Barmar i get what you mean now. However the same code is not working for picks. I just replaced 'entry_history' with 'picks' but its showing undefined index error.

Comment: There's no `id` in `picks`, use `element` instead.

Comment: @Barmar yeah that was a stupid mistake, i figured it out instantly. Thanks for all the help!